# How to generate an excel file and save it directly to a path in Django

Tags: python, django, excel, xls, xlwt

I am new to Django and I was wondering if the following is possible:

**Now**, in my django app(**not admin page**) I create **xls** files using the **xlwt** library.
Pushing a button the user choose where he wants to save the generated file, **but** **isn't** what I want.

**The ideal for me is** when the user clicks on the "Save Excel" button then I want the file to be generated and directly be saved in a specific path in the server or in the database(via FileField), not somewhere in the user's pc.
Without asking the user .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just specify the path as a string argument in save, as you do.

```
when clicked:
    from xlwt import Workbook
    wb = Workbook()
    sheet1 = wb.add_sheet("Sheet 1")
    wb.save("/tmp/workbook.xls")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed, when I specify the path in save() solves my problem. So easy. So fast.